# flink streaming window trigger

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have flink stream and I am calucating few things on some time window say 30 seconds.

here what happens it is giving me result my aggregating previous windows as well.

say for first 30 seconds I get result 10.

next thiry seconds I want fresh result, instead I get last window result + new 
and so on.

so my question is how I get fresh result for each window.

Comment: You might give us an idea of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [purging](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html#built-in-and-custom-triggers) trigger. What you want is FIRE_AND_PURGE (emit and remove window content), what the default flink trigger does is FIRE (emit and keep window content).

```
input
    .keyBy(...)
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(30))

    // The important part: Replace the default non-purging ProcessingTimeTrigger
    .trigger(new PurgingTrigger[..., TimeWindow](ProcessingTimeTrigger))

    .reduce(...)
```

For a more in depth explanation have a look into [Triggers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html#triggers) and [FIRE vs FIRE_AND_PURGE](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html#fire-and-purge).

> A Trigger determines when a window (as formed by the window assigner) is ready to be processed by the window function. Each WindowAssigner comes with a default Trigger. If the default trigger does not fit your needs, you can specify a custom trigger using trigger(...).
>
> When a trigger fires, it can either FIRE or FIRE_AND_PURGE. While FIRE **keeps the contents of the window**, FIRE_AND_PURGE **removes its content**. By default, the pre-implemented triggers simply FIRE without purging the window state.

Comment: Say I using 30 seconds tumbling windows and I want to do some computation in each window and pass it on to subsequent window. Do I need use `ProcessingTimeTrigger.create()` or `PurgingTimeTrgger.create(ProcessingTimeTrigger.create())`. If it is 30 seconds tumbling window...isn't the window content already gone after 30 seconds? If so can we just use `ProcessingTimeTrigger.create()`?

Comment: I am failing to understand why the window content remains? Also when you say window content do you mean the events that belong to window or the result of the computation from the events of a window? which one will be purged if I use PurgingTrigger?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you describe can be found in Tumbling Windows: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html#tumbling-windows

A bit more detail and/or code would help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm little late into this question but I encountered the same issue with OP's. What I found out later was a bug in my own code. FYI my mistake could be good reference for your problem.

```
// Old code (modified to be an example):
val tenSecondGrouping: DataStream[MyCustomGrouping] = userIdsStream
      .keyBy(_.somePartitionedKey)
      .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
      .trigger(ProcessingTimeTrigger.create())
      .aggregate(new MyCustomAggregateFunc(new MyCustomGrouping()))
```

Bug happened at **new MyCustomGrouping**: I unintentionally created a singleton MyCustomGrouping object and reusing it in MyCustomAggregateFunc. As more tumbling windows created, the later aggregation results grow crazy! The fix was to create new MyCustomGrouping each time MyCustomAggregateFunc is triggered. So:

```
// New code, problem solved
          ...
          .aggregate(new MyCustomAggregateFunc(() => new MyCustomGrouping())) 
// passing in a func to create new object per trigger
```